# VueJS props - How can i avoid "class" attribute inheritance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

VueJS auto inherit [Non-Prop Attributes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Non-Prop-Attributes), it's great for data-* attributes.

But we don't want to inherit "class" & "style" attributes to save our core-components from any layout change by any new developer.(Because we want all styling of component within it's style file)

There is `inheritAttrs: false` to avoid "non-prop attribute" inheritance but:

> Note: this option does not affect class and style bindings.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs

So suggestions to avoid "class" & "style" inheritance in core component?

**Update:**

Suggested solution:

```
<template>
 <div ref="root" class="hello">Hi</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
   this.$refs.root.className = 'hello'
  }
 }
</script>
```

But suggested solution even complicated when depend on component's attributes:

```
Vue.component('my-feedback', {
        props: ['type'],
        data: function(){
            var vm = this;
            return {
                classes: {
                    'my-feedback-info': vm.type === 'info',
                    'my-feedback-note': vm.type === 'note',
                    'my-feedback-warning': vm.type === 'warning',
                    'my-feedback-success': vm.type === 'success'
                }
            };
        },
        template: `
                    <div class="my-feedback" :class="classes">
                        <slot></slot>
                    </div>
                `
    });
```

**Update** [20th May 2018]:

Got answer via VueJS's Chat channel - https://discordapp.com/channels/325477692906536972/325479107012067328

Solved JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/53xuhamt/28/

**Update** [28th April 2021]

In Vue3, we could disable attribute inheritance via:

```
 inheritAttrs: false,
```

Vue3 Doc - https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/awan/oz5fbm2k/

Comment: Like @Decade Moon, I think there is no proper way of doing it. I can imagine a way to do it, but it's not very clean, nor easy to maintain. In each or your child components, you could do this: `mounted() { this.$el.className = 'only classes you want'; }`

Comment: Even if you remove `class` and `style` attributes from a component's root element, that won't prevent styles from cascading into the component from parents. Just define **all** the style rules that you don't want overridden in the component and make sure that new developers don't use `!important`

Comment: @Awan nice to add the link to ypur solution. But please consider writing your own answer with explanation and code, instead of relying on external source which may be removed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't opt out of this behavior, unless it's a functional component.

Comment: "class" seems not available in functional component's context - https://jsfiddle.net/awan/53xuhamt/

Comment: Class and style bindings are available in the vnode's `data` object under the properties `class`, `staticClass`, `style` and `staticStyle`, but only if they were set in the template. In your fiddle you have not specified any class or styles so they're absent in the vnode.

Comment: Basically, i am trying to skip  `class="testing"` on root of "nsc-option", so "ignore-class" is write directive to handle that?

Comment: `nsc-option` is not a functional component, so you can't prevent Vue from applying the `testing` class to the root element of that component (whatever that ends up being).

Answer (score 4):

Pretty hacky solution but this worked for me

```
data(){
   return {staticClass: ''}
},
mounted(){
   // Capture the classes and use them on nested elements where desired
   this.staticClass = this.$el.classList.toString()

   // Remove the classes from the root element
   this.$el.setAttribute('class', '')
}
```